# Connect to Android device as Proxy Server, through public IP

Tags: android, proxy, proxy-server

I want to use my Android device as Proxy Server. I was trying to use [Proxy Server app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.proxyserver&hl=en) and [Server Ultimate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate&hl=en). When I connect through WIFI -
 a proxy server is working, but when I disconnect from wifi and I trying to connect through my public IP, it doesn't work. Maybe I need to edit some firewall rules on my device?

I use an HTC one m8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem with a mobile provider. Most mobile providers **block incoming connection** to the phone. But you can connect with your provider and ask to allow the incoming connection, but it's not a good idea and sometimes it's not possible.